# Online Hotel Booking project - Need some logic building tips to prevent code duplication

Tags: php, laravel

**Project**: Online Hotel Booking portal
**Page**: User dashboard. Here user can add property and details (basic details, rooms, amenities, etc.)

**Problem**: 
In the **User Dashboard** page, we ave several pages (Basic details, policies, room details, images, etc). One controller for each controller. For each controller, I am using a middleware **VerifyPropertyUserMiddleware**. Now I require fetching **Property** model in every single controller.

```php
$ppt = PropertyMaster::findOrFail($pID);
```

Solutions that I can think of

1. Create this instance in middleware and pass it to the controller. (but I think middlewares are not supposed to do this job)
2. Create a trait, inside that trait create a method **getProperty** (but code duplication is still a problem as I will have to call the method in every controller)
3. Use sessions. But still, code duplication is still there because in every controller I will have to check whether the laravel session has **$ppt** variable or not.

Comment: I both do and don't follow the problem. I would think [Route Model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding) would suffice. However, maybe it's not in the url? Where does it come in? What you're describing is enrichment, I just don't quite see the entrypoint(s). You would probably also want transport middleware to perform enrichment (e.g. a bus with middleware that can read objects in transit by type and enrich from a resource based on type and identity), if you're not enriching through route parameters.

Comment: Use blade templates to keep the views dry, and traits/a parent controller and polymorphic children for the controllers. Pass the dashboard "type" as a URI component in a single route for each type.

Comment: If you really wanted to use middleware, make an interface for the loading method and in your middleware look for that interface and call that method. For http, I'd still just use the Route Model feature instead of middleware, unless you can't put it in the url or need more control.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a trait used to enrich an object during construction. This particular mode of enrichment means when your upstream object is instantiated, you'll then have the property in all it's glory to work with downstream, or an exception to handle.

```
trait PropertyAware
{
    private $property;

    private function loadProperty(int $id): void
    {
        $this->property = PropertyMaster::findOrFail($id);
    }
}

class PropertyFoo
{
    use PropertyAware;

    public function __construct(int $propertyId)
    {
        $this->loadProperty($propertyId);
    }
}
```

As far as using the trait on a controller, I would tend to prefer a boundary operation and get the Property object [fulfilled from the URL by contract](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding):

```
Route::get('dashboard/properties/{property}', function (App\Property $property) {
    // Use the hydrated $property.
});
```

That will make more sense than using a trait (or using a trait on a base controller, which seems odd to do), and then passing a trait method an id.

Generally I would recommend enrichment privately applied, bracketing an envelope process perhaps, where in transit it's an identifier, but when the message is opened or applied (as in a url request), it's enriched or enrichable by trait.

In this case, the enrichment happens in a url boundary operation, or when unwrapped to pass a message to a handler of some sort (a bus pattern). The attempt here is skinny objects that interpret by nature into known representations (controller pattern using Route Models, for instance), or a property dictionary object that can de-reference it's own relationships (an object of trait).